# Parse xml like string using PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have a string that is of the format:

```
 <!--Vendor: A, Format: IFrame, IO: -->
 <iframe src="xyz.com "scrolling="no" width="180" height="150" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="Advertisement"></iframe>
```

This looks xml like string to me. However $xml=new SimpleXMLElement($string) gives format error.
I tried adding  in end but no use.
I need to extract various parameters out of this. What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: Looks like HTML to me ?

Comment: It does not have the html start and end tags though

Comment: Does it have XML start tags then? It's still HTML.

Comment: No. I just have the string in the above-mentioned format.

Comment: @Prix: I dont think so. Since this does not have xml or html tags it is not getting accepted as html or xml. So I am unable to use those.

Comment: That's because you're reading it using an incorrect way as pointed on the above mentioned thread.

Comment: Sorry. I got the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's HTML and can be parsed as HTML, try this :

```
<?php
    $html = '<!--Vendor: A, Format: IFrame, IO: --><iframe src="xyz.com "scrolling="no" width="180" height="150" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="Advertisement"></iframe>';

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $iframe = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    $iframe_scrolling = $iframe->item(0)->getAttribute('scrolling');

    echo $iframe_scrolling; // outputs 'no'
?>
```